# Could not decode the JSON string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I could not convert the JSON string to array using PHP. Here is my code:

```
$edu=$_POST['edu'];
echo ($edu);
```

The above line is giving the below output.

```
'[{"uname":"univ1","year":"2017","description":"hello"},{"uname":"univ2","year":"2016","description":"hello des"}]'
```

I need to convert this to array using below code.

```
$eduArr=json_decode($edu,true);
print_r($eduArr);
```

But here I am getting the output as `(empty)`. I need to convert the above string to array.

Comment: `$edu = trim($_POST['edu'], "'");` maybe

Comment: what's the json_last_error says ?

Comment: @hassan : how to check the error ?

Comment: http://php.net/json_last_error

Comment: That string decodes just fine. Add `echo json_last_error_msg();` after your `json_decode()` and see if you get some error message that will help

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You json string is not a valid json. It have extra `'` on both side of the string.

From your echo result the `'` is output on each side of the string. For a json string the `'` shoudn't be there.

You can check the [live demo here](https://eval.in/804867) have a good understanding.

```
$eduArr=json_decode(trim($edu, '\''),true);
print_r($eduArr);
```

Comment: if I will have `"[{\"uname\": \"Trident Academy Of Creative Technology\", \"year\": \"2011\", \"description\": MCA\"}]"` data then how to trim.

Comment: You needn't. Have you try it?

Comment: No,I have not tried but the data like this will come then how to get the expected output.

Comment: It's because your json string is invalid.  `MCA\"` should `\"MCA\"` You can check it [here](https://eval.in/804981)

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me:

```
$json = '[{"uname":"univ1","year":"2017","description":"hello"},{"uname":"univ2","year":"2016","description":"hello des"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I know its working while direct string is given but while I am getting the data in post method in this case not working